# why coaxial cable not used in oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, cables

we usually do not use coaxial cables inside oscilloscope, so what is the reason?
what are the conditions which are not feasible for using coaxial cables here?

Comment: Because the signal on good scopes is pre-amplified as soon as it hits the PCB to avoid being contaminated by noise. Good probes (and expensive) actually have the pre-amp in the probe.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside oscilloscope"? Do you mean in the instrument itself? Why do you think they do not use coaxial cables?

Comment: Because a good impedance controlled PCB design works just as well and is *WAY* easier (and cheaper) to automate in mass production (custom coax will always be a manual assembly job)

Answer (score 2):

Scope signals capable of 30MHz usually have controlled impedances.

**Rule#1**

> It is impossible to have signal integrity when the rise time is faster than the propagation delay of the signal unless you have controlled matched impedances. Otherwise you automatically get ringing.

Ground lead inductance is a major cause of ringing even in coaxial probes that must be avoided for measurements>30MHz or Tr<10ns by removing tip & gnd clip and only using tip/barrel ring.

e.g. stripline, microstrip or braided coax. or in high end scopes only semi-rigid coax. are used with SMA or similar RF connectors.